# What are the system sound ids for the new keyboard clicks in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, audiotoolbox

**General**
I'm developing a third party keyboard and am currently trying to mimic the new keyboard clicks that Apple introduced in iOS 10b4. 


**Current Situation**
The regular  click sound can be played using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104)` but I can't seem to find the System Sound IDs for the two new other sounds. I've found the location of their `.caf` equivalents but those are way too loud to use, even after adjusting their volume using `AVAudioPlayer`.
**Question**
Is it possible to obtain the system sound ids of the new click sounds?

**Extra**

If anyone wants the `.caf` file paths for personal use, here they are:

```
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/key_press_click.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/key_press_delete.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/key_press_modifier.caf
```

Comment: Please review the answer and mark it as answered if you find it useful

Comment: @LA sorry just got some time to myself. How exactly did you find them, if I may ask?

Comment: I created a demo app for that :) think UILabel next to a Play UIButton, and two other buttons to up/down the ID number :) took some 10-15 min, but it was worth it. Now my (and hopefully yours and others) custom keyboard is iOS10 sounds ready!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**iOS 10.0 - iOS 11.0 b5**

Press Click - ID: 1123

Press Delete - ID: 1155

Press Modifier - ID: 1156

Comment (1): Same IDs work for iOS 11 beta 5

Answer (score 6):

Implemented in swift using an enum (extend with your own other system sound id's):

```
import AudioToolbox


enum SystemSound: UInt32 {

    case pressClick    = 1123
    case pressDelete   = 1155
    case pressModifier = 1156

    func play() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.rawValue)
    }

}
```

and use like this:

```
@IBAction func pressedDigit(sender : UIButton) {
    SystemSound.pressClick.play()
}
```